# How do I push multiple data as an object into my backend using Typescript in React?

Tags: javascript, typescript, forms, object

I am quite new to typescript and am struggling to push an object into the backend. I am creating a form where I get the user's graduation info and post it into the backend.

The data should look like this in the backend:
"education":[{"place":"A","description":"Learned subject A","year":"2000"}, {"place":"B","description":"Learned subject B","year":"2011"}]

However, I am getting errors where "the type is not assignable to string" or "Property 'name' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes'".

Here is my parent component and the handleEducation function is not working too:

```js
import React, { useState, ChangeEvent, FormEvent } from "react";
import InputForm from "./InputForm";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";

export default function Form() {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [education, setEducation] = useState({
    place: "",
    description: "",
    year: "",
  });

  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleChange = (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    switch (event.target.name) {
      case "country":
        setName(event.target.value);
        break;
      default:
    }
  };

  const handleEducation = (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setEducation({
      place: event.target.value,
      description: event.target.value,
      year: event.target.value,
    });
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (event: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    await axios.post(`http://localhost:3000`, {
      name,
      education,
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <InputForm
        name={name}
        education={education}
        handleChange={handleChange}
        handleSubmit={handleSubmit}
        handleEducation={handleEducation}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is the child component:

```js
interface currUser {
  name: string;
  education: Array<"">;
  handleChange: (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void;
  handleSubmit: (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => void;
  handleEducation: (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void;
}

export default function InputForm({
  name,
  education,
  handleChange,
  handleSubmit,
  handleEducation,
}: currUser) {
  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div>
          <label placeholder="name">Name</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Test"
            name="name"
            value={name}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="container">
          <div>
            <h3 className="card-title">Education</h3>
          </div>
          <form>
            <div>
              <div>
                <label>Institute/Organisation*</label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  name="organisation"
                  value={education.place}
                  onChange={handleEducation}
                />
              </div>
              <div>
                <label>Graduation year</label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  name="year"
                  value={education.year}
                  onChange={handleEducation}
                />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div>
              <label>Description*</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                name="description"
                value={education.description}
                onChange={handleEducation}
              />
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is my DB Schema:

[image]

How should I fix it? Thank you very much!

Comment: can you show me your schema?

Comment: Hi! I've added the db schema. It's a simple database schema. So the education is a JSON and it stores an object containing "description, place, and year".

Comment: change name type as `string`, you passing string but schema declared as char

Comment: Oh sorry. I changed it to string for name so it is working but the education is not

Comment: now what kinda error your getting?

Comment: The error shown in the parent component is: 
"Type '{ place: string; description: string; year: string;}' is not assignable to type 'string'.
The expected type comes from property 'education' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & currUser'.ts(2322)"

In the child component, the error is "Property 'description','year', 'place' does not exist on type 'string'.ts(2339)"